# How to get content from specific culture in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco8

I have biligngual website with German language set as default language and I am trying to get English content nodes from my SurfaceController like this:

```
Umbraco.Content(ID);
```

And i have tried to change curent culture like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

But without success.

Comment: Have you looked at the new language variants in V8? https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Backoffice/Variants/ - and here's how you do it in the frontend: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Design/Rendering-Content/

Comment: I have found the answer  on Umbraco forum , after days of searching

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
private readonly IVariationContextAccessor _variationContextAccessor;

public ContentApiController(IVariationContextAccessor variationContextAccessor)
{
    _variationContextAccessor = variationContextAccessor;
}

public IHttpActionResult Get(int id, string culture)
{
    _variationContextAccessor.VariationContext = new VariationContext(culture);
    var cnt = Umbraco.Content(id);
    return Ok(cnt.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know, why this has so little upvotes - this is a big and common issue, and your answer is perfectly working.